# Stay On React Page After HTTP Post Request to Flask

Tags: javascript, reactjs

After I complete a POST request to a Flask backend from a React form, is there a way I can remain on the React frontend (localhost 3000) instead of switching to the Flask backend (localhost 5000). I do not want to redirect in my flask backend.

Relevant code:

```
export const DateForm = () => {

    return (
        <div>
            <form method='post' action='/acceptDates'>
                <label> Enter Dates:
                </label>
                <br></br>
                <input type="text" id='startDate' name='startDate' />
                <br></br>
                <input type="text" id='endDate' name='endDate' />
                <br></br>
                <input type='submit' value='submit' />
            </form>
        </div>

    )
}
```

```
@app.route('/acceptDates', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def get_dates():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        sd = request.form.get('startDate')
        return "received dates"
```

After submitting the form, I am switched to my Flask localhost but I want to stay on React.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this!

```
export const DateForm = () => {
  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("handleSubmit Runs");
    // Do post request or get request
    // Code here
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <label> Enter Dates:</label>
        <br></br>
        <input type="text" id="startDate" name="startDate" />
        <br></br>
        <input type="text" id="endDate" name="endDate" />
        <br></br>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank you! It works, but could you please help me create my post request from my original code? I am not sure how to do it when it isn't in a form.